# java CsvToBeanBuilder

Tags: java

Пытаюсь считать csv файл

```
package chemicalcalc;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

public class ChemicalCalc {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    List<ChemicalElement> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader("src\\elements.csv")).withType(ChemicalElement.class).build().parse();

    beans.forEach(c -> {System.out.println(c);});
    }
}
```

И сам класс

```
package chemicalcalc;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByPosition;

public class ChemicalElement {
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
private String Element;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
private int Number;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
private String Symbol;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 3)
private float Weight;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 4)
private float Boil;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 5)
private float Melt;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 6)
private float Density;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 7)
private float Vapour;
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 8)
private float Fusion;
}
```

В итоге получаю ошибку - не находит класс

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils
at com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder.withErrorLocale(CSVParserBuilder.java:210)
at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder.buildParser(CsvToBeanBuilder.java:194)
at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder.build(CsvToBeanBuilder.java:145)
at chemicalcalc.ChemicalCalc.main(ChemicalCalc.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1
```

Comment: Покажите ваш pom.xml файл

Comment: Оказалось нужно просто установить библиотеки